# How to select a connection string dynamically from the config file from a session variable?

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

What am trying to create is a single login screen that connects the users to different databases depending on a certain code that each user has.

i have created some keys in my config file which corresponds to the user codes as follows

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ch001" value="h001"/>
<add key="ch002" value="h002"/>
</appSettings>
```

Then i have created connections string as follows

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Dbconn_h001" connectionString="XXX" providerName="XXX"/>
<add name="Dbconn_h002" connectionString="XXX" providerName="XXX"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then i have created a class to get the key value corresponding to the connection string as follows

```
Imports System.Web.Compilation
```

Imports System.CodeDom
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ConnStringExpressionBuilder
    Inherits ExpressionBuilder

```
Public Shared Function GetEvalData(ByVal expression As String, ByVal target As Type, ByVal entry As String) As Object

    Return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Dbconn_" & System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(HttpContext.Current.Session("code").ToString))
End Function
Public Overrides Function GetCodeExpression(ByVal entry As BoundPropertyEntry, ByVal parsedData As Object, ByVal context As ExpressionBuilderContext) As CodeExpression
    Dim type1 As Type = entry.DeclaringType
    Dim descriptor1 As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type1)(entry.PropertyInfo.Name)
    Dim expressionArray1(2) As CodeExpression
    expressionArray1(0) = New CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.Expression.Trim())
    expressionArray1(1) = New CodeTypeOfExpression(type1)
    expressionArray1(2) = New CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.Name)
    Return New CodeCastExpression(descriptor1.PropertyType, New CodeMethodInvokeExpression(New CodeTypeReferenceExpression(MyBase.GetType()), "GetEvalData", expressionArray1))
End Function
```

End Class

The issue is

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(HttpContext.Current.Session("code").ToString)
```

returns  a null reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Your `Session("code")` probably is NULL or not `ch001` or `ch002`. Debug your code and check the value of the Session.

Answer (score 0):

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection()) 
{
 var connString=ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["keyname"];
 conn.ConnectionString = connString;
// using the code here...
}
```

and in config file save like
   `<add key="ch001" value="YourConnectionString" />`

Comment: keyname will come from your session

Comment: if the SqlDataSource control is embedded inside the EditTemplate then it will not be accessible from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

After a long hustle i figured it out i  created this expression builder class

```
Public Class ConnStringExpressionBuilder
Inherits ExpressionBuilder

Public Shared Function GetEvalData(ByVal expression As String, ByVal target As Type, ByVal entry As String) As Object

    Return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(HttpContext.Current.Session("code").ToString())).ToString()

End Function
Public Overrides Function GetCodeExpression(ByVal entry As BoundPropertyEntry, ByVal parsedData As Object, ByVal context As ExpressionBuilderContext) As CodeExpression
    Dim type1 As Type = entry.DeclaringType
    Dim descriptor1 As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(type1)(entry.PropertyInfo.Name)
    Dim expressionArray1(2) As CodeExpression
    expressionArray1(0) = New CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.Expression.Trim())
    expressionArray1(1) = New CodeTypeOfExpression(type1)
    expressionArray1(2) = New CodePrimitiveExpression(entry.Name)
    Return New CodeCastExpression(descriptor1.PropertyType, New CodeMethodInvokeExpression(New CodeTypeReferenceExpression(MyBase.GetType()), "GetEvalData", expressionArray1))
End Function
```

End Class

Then in my markup i call the class like this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Ds" runat="server" ProviderName="Mysql.Data.MysqlClient"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnStringExpression:Dbconn %>" SelectCommand="XXX"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then from the code behind

```
Using conn = getConnect(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings(Session("code").ToString()))
        conn.Open()

        Try
           //logic
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        conn.Close()
    End Using
```